# Sort input dialog ,HTML

Tags: html, forms

```
<form>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    Email address: <input type="text" name="emailAddress">
</form>
```

How to format the input fields to be aligned under each other?

Comment: format how? sorted by what?

Comment: i mean i need the input dialog to be aligned under each other

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+form+layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your inputs' corresponding titles in `<label>`-s, and beside the fact it makes more semantic sense it allows you to style everything the way you want it:

***HTML***

```
<form>
    <label for="...">First name:</label> <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    <label for="...">Last name:</label> <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    <label for="...">Email address:</label> <input type="text" name="emailAddress">
</form>
```

***CSS***

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9XA2T/)